# Managing user status notification

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm has installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 and installed Gnome-shell...all OK, but on user notification menu when i'm has logged, on right side of user pic have an disabled combo user user status..by default is Unavailable.

How i can enable this combo and, how i manage this user status ? Any docs/sample?

An image:
[image]

I'm confused and believe that i don't search correctly about this question. :/

Comment: Have you tried clicking on 'Unavailable' and selecting 'Available'?

Comment: You have to add an Account (of those supported by the Gnome Online Accounts service)  then you can change your status.

Answer (score 1):

Works...

I was installed **Empathy package** and this combo be available. On Empathy I was configured my Google Account and linked with Web Account (managed on system).

Now I'll test the messages receive like e-mails, chat, etc. to check if it's working.

Leveraging this question, default **Gnome-shell** doesn't have a zipped files viewer, and I don't want install all ubuntu-desktop package, only a simple viewer for this.

Someone know a name of zip|tar| viewer like 'Ark' of KDE ?

Comment: This thread [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1537105) solve my last question...The **Gnome package manager**